# hard drive wont boot - fedora 11

Tags: linux, installation

i was trying to install Linux on a old usb hard drive i have and i installed it onto the drive (from a .iso cd, i clicked install onto hard drive from the desktop) then rebooted. i tried to boot Linux from it but it did not work then i tried booting of the my main hard drive that has windows 7 on it and i get "failure to boot hard drive" (or something close to that). i reloaded fedora from the CD and looked and my main hard drive still has all of the files from windows and also the usb hard drive has files that look like they are from the Linux install. i do not know why it's giving me the hard drive error but i need to fix it fast because i need to do my school and it's on windows, any questions just ask.

Answer (score 1):

You propably killed your MBR (Master Boot Record).

http://www.ehow.com/how_4836283_repair-mbr-windows.html

Comment: +1 - It's a common problem. But easily fixed thankfully. :)